# Scheduling an event for everyone 1ms using Windows and C++ chrono - am I asking for too much?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, c++-chrono

I have some code which is like this:

```
    while(true)  
    {
    std::chrono::milliseconds NowSinceEpoch = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    if((NowSinceEpoch - LastUpdateSinceEpoch >= std::chrono::milliseconds(1)
    { 
       DoSomething()
       LastTimeSinceEpoch = duration_cast<milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());

    }
```

Is this a bit too much for Windows and Chrono to handle? Can it really work with such small units of time? I've read a lot about Windows struggling beyond 10ms. Any other timer libraries I could try

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you just wait (sleep) instead of busy waiting?

Comment: A very good question, I'm not using a sleep because my software is used on a virtual machine, and I've had some odd behaviour with sleeps on VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still decide to spin-wait instead of sleeping the thread, which might give you better granularity (`sleep_for` only guarantees that the thread will sleep for *at* *least* the given time), you should use `high_resolution_clock` instead.

```
while(true)  
{
    auto lastDoSomethingTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    if((high_resolution_clock::now() - lastDoSomethingTime) >= milliseconds(1))
    { 
       DoSomething()
       lastDoSomethingTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need something like this:

```
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using clock = steady_clock;

    auto time_up = clock::now() + milliseconds(1);

    while(true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(time_up);

        // emit event

        // set time_point for next millisecond
        time_up += milliseconds(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`std::thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) instead.

```
while(true)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    DoSomething();
}
```

Your solution will consume 100% CPU while waiting to call `DoSomething()`. By calling `sleep_for()` you free up time which the OS may use for other tasks.

Comment: Technically, this schedules an event for every (1 ms + duration of `DoSomething()`), subject to the resolution of `sleep_for`, not every 1 ms. [sleep_until](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) is one alternative.

Comment: Well spotted :-) However, that is how the OP code works as well... (which is just a lucky coincidence for me)